# auditd not loading plugin on Debian 10

Tags: linux, auditd

I am trying to load a plugin (laurel) in auditd on Debian 10.  It loads and works on Debian 11 but I need it to run on Debian 10.  I have the laurel binary in `/etc/audit/plugins.d`.

When I begin auditd in the foreground (using `auditd -f`) it reads the `auditd.conf` file and runs file.  However, I do not see it loading any plugins.  How can I further debug this problem?  Why is it not loading the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the plugin program permissions to 750?
I couldn't load it before, but then I used the command `auditd -f` and it showed that the plugin program permissions were incorrect.